# How does Hibernate function Restrictions.allEq(Map<String, Object>) treat null values?

Tags: hibernate, equals, isnull, restrictions

I'm wondering how the Hibernate function `Restrictions.allEq(Map<String, Object> ...)` treats null values inside input Map (if as multiple `Restrictions.eq(String, Object)` or `Restrictions.eqOrIsNull(String, Object)`) or whatelse).
After a quick search from Google, I couldn't find anything specific from Hibernate documentation, and only a source says that `Restrictions.allEq(...)` is equivalent to `multiple Restrictions.eq(String, Object)` (see [here](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/2830582/)).
I'm not sure that is the correct answer, so I'm asking here.
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After downloading sources of Hibernate (4.3.6.Final), and a little inspection, I've finally found the answer: `Restrictions.allEq(Map<String, Object>)` is translated as a bunch of `Restrictions.eq(String, Object)` and consequently a `null` value is remapped as the String `"null"` (which may be or may be not the correct translation, based on the specific application).
In my case, I needed to use multiple `Restrictions.eqOrIsNull(String, Object)` to correctly manage my input `Map<String, Object>`.
I hope this question will be useful to someone else.